# Sound over HDMI is 2x as slow after resuming from standby

Tags: sound, hdmi

I have an extremely frustrating problem with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bits on my Dell E7450: when I connect a TV over HDMI (tried a [Samsung 1080p TV](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/UN40EH5300FXZA) via [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0031TRZX2) 25-ft [high-speed HDMI cable](https://superuser.com/a/397734/33589) with Ethernet support, and also a Visio TV via a 6-ft cable), **MOST OFTEN BUT NOT ALWAYS** the sound is 2x as slow, and everything else, e.g. video playback, is dragged down to slow-motion.

In other words, testing audio via Speaker Testing goes "Frooont Leeeft" in a low-pitch male voice (the normal is a crisp "Front Left" in a female voice").

[image: FUCK THIS PIECE OF SHIT]

After some frustratingly random combination of reconnecting the cable, switching among display mirroring modes and rebooting, the sound returns to normal - as long as the laptop doesn't enter standby mode.

This drives me nuts. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complement the above, if you read through the [comments on the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1580882/comments/18), you'll see that there is a fix/workaround which consists in the manual installation of an updated package from [here](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages) ([further instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS)).

Basically for a 16.04 desktop, I chose the "daily" build of package `oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-xenial-dkms` at the bottom of the page, then:

1. click the downward arrow on the left
2. click `oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-xenial-dkms_0.<timestamp>~ubuntu16.04.1_all.deb` (at bottom of page) which opens in the package manager
3. approve installation
4. reboot

I experienced this bug on my laptop (a ThinkPad X1c3) when it was still running trusty; when upgrading to Xenial didn't fix the issue, I thought it was time to do smth about it.  Glad it's finally fixed!

Comment: I still occasionally get this annoying behavior, a year later, or no sound goes to the HDMI device at all. Frustrating AF.

Comment: Didn't fixed,  HDMI sounds low pitch like before.

Answer (score 2):

A bug for this behavior was reported in May 2016:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1580882

The workaround suggested in the 2017-Jan comment worked for me as of July 2017:

```
pulseuadio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

<sub>(Since I got no answers on this question, I had initially reported the bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1620192; it was marked duplicate.)</sub>